# Order of finite groups with automorphism groups of prime order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be a finite group such that $|Aut(G)| = p$, where $p$ is a prime number. Prove that $|G| \le 3$

I found out that in this case, $G$ must be Abelian. However, I'm having trouble showing that $|G| \le 3$. How can I prove this?

Comment: Where $p$ is a prime, right? (You should mention such things).

Comment: oh yes sorry about that

Comment: It's not true. The cyclic groups of orders 4 and 6 both have automorphism groups of order 2.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: since $G$ is abelian, the map $\phi : G \rightarrow G$, defined by $\phi(x)=x^{-1}$ is an automorphism of order at most $2$.